# Angular google maps not reloading when I change options

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am trying to create an angular app with angular goggle maps components. My app has a dark-light theme switcher. I have created two map styles - a night style for the dark theme and a light version for the light theme respectively. When the theme is changed, I update the map options to change the map id as per the theme selection. But, it does not get reflected in the map appearance. My map markers are alright. Hence I didn't add that part of code here. Also, please note that I have masked my map ids in the below code.

My maps component ts

```
 @Input() position: GeolocationPosition;

  public markers: any[] = [];
  public options: google.maps.MapOptions;
  public mapId: string;

  private darkModeKey: string = "dark-mode";
  public themingSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private secretsService: SecretsService,
    private themingService: ThemingService,
    private storageService: StorageService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setMapOptions();

    this.loadMarkers();

    this.themingSubscription = this.themingService.theme.subscribe((theme: string) => {
      this.setMapOptions();
    });
  }

  private setMapOptions()
  {        
    this.options = {
      center: {
        lat: this.position.coords.latitude,
        lng: this.position.coords.longitude
      },
      zoom: 14,
      mapId: this.storageService.getItemByKey(this.darkModeKey) ?
        <dark-map-id> :
        <light-map-id>,
      maxZoom: 30,
      minZoom: 5,
    } as google.maps.MapOptions;
  }
```

html

```
<div>
  <google-map [options]="options" [width]="700" [height]="500" >
    <map-marker *ngFor="let marker of markers" [position]="marker.position" [label]="marker.label"
      [title]="marker.title" [options]="marker.options"></map-marker>
  </google-map>
</div>
```

what am I doing wrong? Or is this some maps component issue?

Comment: Have you tried to run the ChangeDetection after you set the options to the `this.options` ? https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#use-markforcheck-with-checkonce-strategy

Comment: @RomanA. I have tried the below but to no avail.  this.themingSubscription = this.themingService.theme.subscribe((theme: string) => {
      this.setMapOptions();
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    });

Answer (score 4):

This could be an issue with Angular not triggering change detection because, each time `this.options` changes, the variable reference doesnot change. Hence, angular thinks its the same value.

Try

```
this.options = {...this.options,
      center: {
        lat: this.position.coords.latitude,
        lng: this.position.coords.longitude
      },
      zoom: 14,
      mapId: this.storageService.getItemByKey(this.darkModeKey) ?
        <dark-map-id> :
        <light-map-id>,
      maxZoom: 30,
      minZoom: 5,
    }
```

Doing it in the es6 way changes reference to the variable as it creates a copy of the original `this.options`.